# play sound i page background

Tags: jquery, html, css

i find this tag play sounds in page background:

```
<embed src="file.wav" autostart="true" loop="false" volume="100" hidden="true" />
```

But i have problam with some browser (FF, Opera) this browser break(stop work).
I thing this tag is very old and now unused.

So how play sound in page background (use html, css or jquery languages)?

Thanks

Comment: `autostart="true"` Oh God please no...

Comment: Please do **not** play audio automatically!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.scriptwell.net/howtoplaysound.htm has a few options, HTML5 is bound to have something although support isn't great yet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<bgsound src="music.wav" loop="infinite">
```